# Opening an eclipse project folder in vs code

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run a simple console output project created from eclipse in vs code but there seems to be a lot of errors.

[image]

Not sure what to do here.
As soon as I edit and save a file in vs code and try to run it in Eclipse, Eclipse also get the same error.

I need to "import" more of these projects and packages already created from Eclipse.

I've already installed the "Extension Pack for Java" from Microsoft and setup the JDK.

Comment: 1. Hover over the code with red underline, is there any quick fixes? 2. Open command palette and choose Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace, does this help?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I've tried the "Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace "already but it still doesnt work. but I think I found the solution. I deleted ".setting" ".classpath" and  ".project" from the project folder and everything works fine in vs code now.

Comment: That's great. Can you write down the solution as an answer and accept it to mark this question as resolved?

Comment: posted an answer, but I'll have to wait until the next day to mark it. thank you again for the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I deleted ".setting", ".classpath" and ".project"
from the project folder and everything works fine in vs code now.

Comment: Juft FI, with VSCode 1.79.2 (in 2023) on Ubuntu 22.04 I didn't even have to remove `.setting, .project, .cproject, .pydevproject`.